# Panel data regression for large datasets (ffdf)

Tags: r

I am using `ffdf` class to store a panel dataset quite big in size. I would like to know if there is any way of running fixed effects regression for data in this class.

```
library(ffbase)
size <- 100000
index <- 100
a <- ffrandom(n=index, rfun = runif)
panel_index <- ffseq_len(index)
times_vec <- ffrep.int(size,times=index)
b <- ffrep.int(a, times=times_vec)
panel_index <- ffrep.int(panel_index, times=times_vec)
error <- ffrandom(n=size*index, rfun=rnorm)
intercept <- ffrep.int(10, times=size*index)
x <- ffrandom(n=size*index, rfun=rnorm)
y <- x+intercept+b+error

dataf <- ffdf(y = y, x = x, panel_index = panel_index) ## on disk
dim(dataf)
```

I would like to run something like

```
library(plm)
fixed <- plm(y ~ x, data=dataf, 
    index="panel_index", model="within")
```

but I get the following error message:

> Error in is.finite(x[[i]]) :
> default method not implemented for type 'list'

what are the alternative packages which can handle `ffdf` data?

Comment: I don't know `plm` so it is not clear what model exactly is estimated, but couldn't you model also be estimated using `lm` (perhaps after some transformations of your data)? In that case you could use `biglm`.

Comment: Thanks! `plm` is used above to calculate within-fixed effects model. `biglm` does with `ffdf` class, I am still trying to figure out how to run fixed/random effect model in `biglm`.

Comment: Random effects models will not work in `biglm`, fixed effects might depending on your exact model.

Comment: @JanvanderLaan Is there any other way, I needed to use more complicated count models including poisson, negative binomial on my dataset.

Comment: I don't know of any packages for panel data that support ffdf's. You may want to check the r-sig-mixed-models mailing list: https://stat.ethz.ch/mailman/listinfo/r-sig-mixed-models